# Python if any statement with or condition

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.5 and I'm trying to create an if statement to check two different variables against two different lists, I tried the following things:

```
if not any(x in colorsA for x in colorsB) or (y in colorsA for y in colorsC):
```

and also

```
if not any(x in colorsA for x in colorsB) or not any(y in colorsA for y in colorsC):
```

but none seem to work, either only the first statement is done or none at all, all the variables are strings. Is there a simple way to do this?

Example:

```
ColorsA = ['red', 'yellow', 'green']
ColorsB = ['red', 'white', 'blue']
ColorsC = ['white', 'blue', 'green']
```

if there is no color from colorsA in either colorsB or in colorsC

print(colorA)

Output: yellow

Comment: Can you give examples for `colorsX` and show us exactly what logic you are trying to apply?

Comment: Can you show us those lists and what exactly the criterion is? There's probably a much easier approach…

Comment: [deMorgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)   `if not (any(x in colorsA for x in colorsB) or any(y in colorsC for y in colorsD)):` - and yes, there are probably much simpler ways. Make  lists into sets and see if the sets have common elements f.e.

Comment: The `any()` ends before the `or`, you minimally have to `or any(...)` but Patrick's comment is the way to go really.

Comment: You mean `print(colorsA)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)). In Python you use the `set` class to interact with sets:

```
ColorsA = ['red', 'yellow', 'green']
ColorsB = ['red', 'white', 'blue']
ColorsC = ['white', 'blue', 'green']

result = set(ColorsA) - (set(ColorsB) + set(ColorsC))
if result:
    print('At least one element in ColorsA is not found in either ColorsB or ColorsC')
else:
    print('All elements in ColorsA are found in either ColorsB or ColorsC')
```

If your sets are very large, building up these `set` objects the first time might be expensive. On the other hand, once you've created a `set` object, they are very fast to use. Checking something like `'yellow' in color_set` will be substantially faster than `'yellow' in color_list`, especially as the size of the set increases.

Answer (score 1):

you could use list comprehension syntax.
I show the derived array result and a final if conditional statement example.

```
ColorsA = ['red', 'yellow', 'green']
ColorsB = ['red', 'white', 'blue']
ColorsC = ['white', 'blue', 'green']

print
print [x for x in ColorsA if x not in ColorsB]
print [x for x in ColorsA if x not in ColorsC]
print [x for x in ColorsA if ((x not in ColorsC) and (x not in ColorsB))]

if (len([x for x in ColorsA if ((x not in ColorsC) and (x not in ColorsB))])==0):
    print "some elements in ColorsA are not found in ColorsB or ColorsC"
else:
    print "All elements in ColorsA are found in either ColorsB or ColorsC"
```

which gives you the output

```
['yellow', 'green']
['red', 'yellow']
['yellow']
some elements in ColorsA are not found in ColorsB or ColorsC
```